# Tried running a script, kept getting "AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist"

Tags: arcpy, merge, attributeerror

Anyone know how i can fix this problem below?

I am trying to merge all the layers under the same name in different subfolders.

```
import arcpy
import os

# parameters
input_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_geodatabase = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# validate output geodatabase name
output_geodatabase = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(output_geodatabase), 
os.path.basename(output_geodatabase).split('.')[0] + '.gdb')

# turn overwrite on
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# make output geodatabase if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_geodatabase):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating output geodatabase...")
    # make sure name is valid
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(os.path.dirname(output_geodatabase), 
os.path.basename(output_geodatabase))


# Making an empty list to put filepaths to feature classes in
arcpy.AddMessage("Scanning input directory...")
merge_dict = {}
# Walking workspace recursively checking type, and appending filepath to list
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(input_folder, 
datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in filenames:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        if not filename in merge_dict:
            merge_dict[filename] = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)]
        else:
            cur = merge_dict[filename]
            cur.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            merge_dict[filename] = cur
arcpy.AddMessage(" -> Found {} different file groups to 
merge".format(len(merge_dict.keys())))



arcpy.AddMessage("Starting merge processes...")
i = 1
tot = len(merge_dict.keys())
for k in merge_dict.keys():
    arcpy.AddMessage(' -> {}/{} {}'.format(i, tot, k))
    # get dataset name
    datasetName = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(merge_dict[k][0]))
    # if output dataset with same name doesn't exist, make it
    if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(output_geodatabase, datasetName)):
        # get spatial reference
        sr = arcpy.Describe(os.path.dirname(merge_dict[k][0])).spatialReference
        arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(output_geodatabase, datasetName, sr)
    # now merge files
    outputMergedFile = os.path.join(output_geodatabase, datasetName, k)
    arcpy.Merge_management(merge_dict[k], outputMergedFile)

    i += 1

arcpy.AddMessage('Done!')
```

Below is the error from ArcGIS Pro:

```
Failed script Merge Data...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Python Script\merge_data.py", line 48, in <module>
    sr = arcpy.Describe(os.path.dirname(merge_dict[k][0])).spatialReference
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist
 Failed to execute (MergeData).
```

Comment: You are trying to describe the GDB to get a spatial reference.  Run Describe on a featureclass.

Comment: can i ask how i can change to that? the script is done by my friend :/ and i dont know how to edit this without any python knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
sr = arcpy.Describe(os.path.dirname(merge_dict[k][0])).spatialReference
```

to this:

```
sr = arcpy.Describe(merge_dict[k][0]).spatialReference
```

The `os.path.dirname()` is being passed a feature class (I think?) in which case it will be returning the workspace.  You want to use the feature class itself, not the workspace to get the spatial reference.

See:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/featureclass-properties.htm

which says that it also includes: 
 http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/dataset-properties.htm